# Java How to do looots of HTTP-Requests in parallel?

Tags: java, http, io, httpclient, selector

Because the servers are really slow, I would like to connect to as many of them as possible in parallel and send HTTP-Requests. However, when I've used lots of threads, the overhead seemed to make healthy connections time out (because the thread wasn't running and couldn't react). People in a previous question told me to use "Selectors" because they use the operating system to know what to read next instead of switching between threads.

I've had a look on the web, but it seems like those selectors are just used for servers with general connections which are receiving requests and not for sending HTTP-Requests?

How can you use those selectors for sending HTTP-Requests and getting the answers as fast as possible while also handling the errors that occur quite often? A tiny bit of code would be cool so that I can get an idea.

Comment: I would try using [sendAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#sendAsync(java.net.http.HttpRequest,java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler)).  If it turns out to be insufficient, you can always specify a [custom Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html#executor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)).

Comment: OMG THAT SOUNDS SO GREAT AND SIMPLE THANK YOU :-)